# NSPlaceholderString Memory Leak with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

at the moment I develop a iOS App with ARC. The app is a storyboard application with two TableViewControllers.

The problem is, that instruments shows me a memory leak in the following case:

> Start of the Application --> MainViewController loaded --> Home Button is pressed --> Local Notification appears --> App starts using the local notification --> AppDelegate get the navigation controller --> Calls function in MainViewController which load the 2. View Controller --> 2. View Controller is shown and User clicks on "Back".

At this point instruments shows me a memory leak:

```
Leaked Object | # | Address   | Size     | Responsible Library | ResponsibleFrame
__NSCFString  | 1 | 0xe40dd30 | 32 Bytes | Foundation          | -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:]
```

When I look into the Stack Trace I can't see any of my own function.

Did I make an mistake in my programming or is this a bug in the Apple Framework.

How can avoid the problem?

[image: The Stack Trace]

Comment: I can't tell how you're calling this, but there is definitely an unbalanced retain/release of a format string in that framework block.  rdar://16400891

Comment: So there is now way how I could found / fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have received this kind of Leaks for NSPlaceholderString . But you can ignore that as it leaks because of Apple Framework and its of only 32 bytes .

Answer (score 1):

To check for any unbalanced retain/releases, run

`Product` > `Analyze` (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>).

If that returns nothing, probably nothing you can do.